# Elasticsearch showing wrong data for Similar query

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Elasticsearch showing wrong data for query.
I have same query in diffrent manner ,first one is

```
**GET  salesindex/salesmarket/368**
```

and result showing correct data which I update
 "DeletedID": 2,

but for

```
POST  salesindex/salesmarket/_search
{ "query":{"bool": {"must": [{"term": {"salesId": 368}}]}}}
```

I got wrong result for same data
 "DeletedID": 1,

Then I clear cache and try ,Its showing same result but after 2 -3 minute its showing correct result.
**salesId is my document Id**
I could not understatnd this behavior of elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

In situation one, where you do a GET by id of the document you get instant access. When you do a query however, as in situation 2, you have to wait for a refresh to occur. If there is no refresh, the new or updated document is not added to the Lucene cache yet. You can also try the same approach with an explicit refresh. Be warned, this is usually not wat you want in production, unless the amount of updates is not to high.

In short:
GET by id: real time
Search: near real time

Hope that helps

Comment: I refresh Index Whenever any change occurs in database,so for each bulk post I refresh the index.But it is not working.(I refresh because I need change instantaneously).Thanks